# Generic Repository implementation fails with IEntity constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic repository and it fails because there is no implicit conversion from the DBML object to the generic entity. I don't know how to make the DBML object inherit from IEntity, or if that is even the solution.

Below are the interfaces and the repository signatures I'm using.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; } 
}

public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    ....
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
{
    ....
}
```

This is the Model class. It fails with the error (below) at line 9 where an instance of the repository class is instantiated in the constuctor. This only started happening after I added the IEntity constraint to the Repository class.

```
public class MyModel
{
    DataContext DC;
    Repository<MyType> MyRep;

    public MyModel()
    {
        DC = new DataContext("ConnStr");
        MyRep = new Repository<MyType>(DC);

    }
}
```

Here is the error : The type cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyType' to 'IEntity'

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like`MyType` is not implementing the `IEntity` interface.

Open your DBML file with an editor and add the following attribute:

```
EntityBase="IEntity"
```

to the `Database` element.

Edit: don't know if that is possible using the UI editor.

Comment: Right, but how do I make a DBML type which is created from auto-generated code implement IEntity?

Comment: Oh, forgot the rest. Edited the answer!

Comment: Where in the DBML files do I need to add that statement? In dbml.layout or designer.cs file?

Comment: Neither, you should directly open the *.dbml file with a text editor.

Comment: I see, you said add it to the database node. Sorry, I missed that. This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

D.R.'s answer solved my problem in the short term, but ultimately I implemented partial classes which extend the DBML objects. This approach solved a couple of issues. First, the DBML file doesn't have to be edited every time there are Database changes. Second, this gives me the ability to add other extension properties and methods to the DBML objects when needed.